# How to position a tab in an app as the last tab

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a business request, saying they want one of the custom tabs (X)  to be the last one on the banner. I know that you can define the ordering of the tabs by:

Setup -> App Setup - > Create -> Apps

is there a way to say for all users of a profile (or set of profiles) make this the last tab?  My hunch is no....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this magic checkbox *"Overwrite users' personal custom app customizations*" when you edit an App or add a new Tab to existing Apps.

[image: overwrite]

But your users will still be able to reorder them afterwards!

Other than that - no idea.

Comment: The part not shown on the screenshot is where you assign the app to Profiles. So if only you'll tick them all I'd say yes. Best option would be to simply experiment with it in a sandbox for example.

Answer (score 0):

Reorder Salesforce Tabs:

I submitted a case ticket to the SF Support and they showed me how to do this.
I have SF Enterprise and you can reorder the tabs this way.
Go to, Setup > Create > Apps

I wanted to change the order of the "Sales" app. 
BTW, The "Sales" app is one of those in the pick list near the upper right of your screen when you first login into SF.

Click Edit to the left of the "Sales" app.
Next add or remove the tabs you want using the "Selected Tabs" and "Available Tabs" lists.
You can change the order of the "Selected Tabs" by moving them "Up" or "Down" using the buttons on the right of the "Selected Tabs" box.

Also make sure you check the box "Overwrite users' personal custom app customizations" so that the tabs and the order shows up this way for all the users.